# attempting to load more items at the end of listview

Tags: android, listview

I am attempting to load more items at the end of listview. upon scolling to the end of the listview only the progressbar is shown but more items is never added to the listview.

```
CustomAdapter adapter; //initialize adapter

@Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return this.parseData();
    }
```

//called in onpost execute

```
adapter=new CustomAdapter(c,spacecrafts);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                }

                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                    if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
                    {
                        if(flag_loading == false)
                        {
                            flag_loading = true;

                            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                            expand = expand + 5;

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Please what could be wrong

Comment: Where do you initialize your adapter?

Comment: CustomAdapter adapter is initialized as an instance variable

Comment: It's not necessary to  call setAdapter of listview each time you update the date, if you implement a right structure you can update your list by calling lv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: please can you show answer

Comment: Please update your question with your adapter code and the initialize code of your adapter

Comment: done editting.... please check

Comment: you are setting a `null` adapter to your listView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173957/discussion-between-rocket-and-mosius).

Comment: please show me where

Answer (score 0):

Do not clear your list and try.

```
spacecrafts.clear();
```

Comment: I think you want to add more data within same list so comment spacecrafts.clear(),you do not need to clear your list

Comment: the same result on commenting out that line

Comment: below spacecrafts.clear(); line you have create the object of 
            Spacecraft spacecraft; comment this line as well and try

Answer (score 0):

Try initialize the Adapter and ArrayList in your class body like bellow:

```
ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts = new ArrayList<Spacecraft>();
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(spacecrafts);
```

Then call this code inside onCreate method

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And after that when you added new items to the list you can notify the adapter by calling:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```